# How to check if a variable equals one of two values if a clean manner in JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement

To check if `x` variable is equal to 1 or 2, i would do normally something like:

```
if (x === 1 || x === 2){
   // ....
}
```

but this can get in some cases very cumbersome.

> **Edit** :I'm working right now on this and writing the fonction name every time i think can be done in a cleaner manner:

```
if (
      this.getNotificationStatus() === 'denied' ||
      this.getNotificationStatus() === 'blocked'
    )
```

Is there any other lighter way to write this?

**THANKS**

Comment: `[1,2].includes(x)`?

Comment: please add a cumbersome example.

Comment: If the comparison involves only two values, then the `if` loop provides better readability

Comment: Note that [Array.prototype.includes() tests reference equality](https://codesearchable.com/it/4531896/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
if ([1, 2].includes(x)) {
  // ....
}
```

Or:

```
if ([1, 2].indexOf(x) > -1) {
  // ....
}
```

Or:

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
    // ....
    break;
  default:
}
```

I don't think they're "lighter" than your solution though.

Comment: Note: `includes` doesn't work prior ES2016. `indexOf` doesn't supported in some old browsers (IE9 for example).

Comment: Yes, and `includes` doesn't work in IE at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([1, 2, 3].includes(x)) {
  // your code here
}
```